# Schengen Visa Refused twice what could i have done wrong?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I recieved spanish schengen visas in the past and most recently i was refused a visa twice in a row which to me was shocking. I provided all the documents requested by the consulate i will provide a list of documents i provide and i cannot figure out what was missing or what went wrong. I would appreciate any clarity on this matter.

Passport and application correclty filled out
Verifiable flight bookings 
Parents bank statement 
Parents home contract in spain where i will be staying 
My assests in home country
Car Title 
Marriage certificate
Daughters birth certificate

What was missing what could have caused the refusals?

Comment: Which box was checked?

Comment: justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable. Which makes NO sense at all considering i used the same documents to obtain the first two visas. The refusal explanation is very vague Gayot Fow. I researched and looked for the sub reason but still didnt make.sense. i really dont know WHY they refused

Comment: We have an article already prepared, please read it carefully. If it does not provide your answer, you will most likely need a specialist. Thanks